# Angular material custom Badge sizing

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

```
<button class="user_badge" mat-raised-button color="primary" matBadge="1000" matBadgePosition="after" matBadgeColor="accent" MatBadgeSize="large">
  <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
  User
</button>
```

I use badge size `"large"`, but some of my data tends to overflow with ellipsis (`...`) I need to increase badge size. How do I increase badge size using css?

[Angular Material Badge Sizing Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/badge/overview#badge-sizing)

Any Help Appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this style. I hope this will work for you

```
.mat-badge-content {
    width: auto;
    display: grid;
    min-width: 32px;
    min-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    top: -20px;
    right: -22px;
}
```

Comment: Be sure your width will be auto otherwise after 5 digit your number will be hidden. Thanks

Comment: I had to use `::ng-deep .mat-badge-content {` for it to work

Answer (score 9):

You can change the following three properties for the class `mat-badge-content`:

```
.mat-badge-content {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Try it in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-badge-size?embed=1&file=app/badge-overview-example.css).

Comment: @Thiyagarajan Have you tried the Stackblitz? It works for me.

Comment: As stated in other questions and answers, the width should be always auto so it won't hide when large numbers appear

Comment: You have a fixed size, large values are still coming with ellipsis.